# How to use a server side variable in javascript with Razor

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a piece of code in a view as

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    var locations = new List<string>();
    var count = 1;
    foreach (var shop in Model)
    {
        locations.Add(string.Format(
                    @"{{
                           title: ""Shop Name: {0}"", 
                           position: new google.maps.LatLng({1}, {2}),
                           icon: ""{3}""
                       }}",
                       shop.ShopName,
                       shop.Location.Latitude,
                       shop.Location.Longitude,
                       count
                    )
                  );

        count++;
    }

    var locationsJson = "[" + string.Join(",", locations.ToArray()) + "]";
}
```

How can I assign the locationsJson to a javascript variable as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsLocations = @locationsJson;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perform your embedded server code ON the server side instead, and then you could make it a property of the model and do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsLocations = @Model.locationsJson;

</script>
```

Comment: He has an object literal, not a string.

Comment: var jsLocations = @Html.Raw(Model.locationsJson)  // handle "" in the json key.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a piece of code in a view as

You absolutely should never have such piece of code in your view. Try this (shorter, better, safer):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsLocations = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $.each(jsLocations, function(index, item) {
        // TODO: do something with the item, for example
        // alert(item.ShopName); or alert(Location.Latitude);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine.

However, you need to escape the values in your JSON, or you'll have an XSS hole.
You should use a real JSON serializer.